# selectOneMenu in a editable dataTable not refreshing

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I am using JSF 2.0 along with Primefaces 5.2.

I have a editable dataTable in my xhtml page which has a selectOneMenu. On rowSelect, I want the selectOneMenu to be populated with values. Following is the code snippet from my xhtml page -

```
    <h:form id="form_defineCustomerEffort">

            ...

            <p:dataTable id="addCustEffortSummTable" var="custeffsumvar" dynamic="true" editable="true"
                value="#{oumOpportunityBean.customEffortEntities}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" 
                selection="#{oumOpportunityBean.selectedCustomEffortForSC}"
                selectionMode="single" scrollWidth="1190" 
                rowKey="#{custeffsumvar.id}" paginator="true"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20,30,50">

                <p:ajax event="rowEdit"
                    listener="#{oumOpportunityBean.onRowEditCustomEffort}"
                    update=":form_defineCustomerEffort:msgs" />
                <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel"
                    listener="#{oumOpportunityBean.onRowCancel}"
                    update=":form_defineCustomerEffort:msgs" />
                <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
                    listener="#{oumOpportunityBean.setSCStaffProfile}" 
                    update=":form_defineCustomerEffort:addCustEffortSummTable:sc_StaffProfileMenuSumm"          
                     />

                <f:facet name="header">Custom Effort</f:facet>

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header"
                        style="width: 500px;white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;white-space: -pre-wrap;white-space: -o-pre-wrap;white-space: pre-wrap;word-break: break-all;white-space: normal;">
                        <h:outputText value="#"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{rowIndex+1}" />
                </p:column>

                ...

                <p:column headerText="Staffing Profile Assignment">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output"
                            style="width: 500px;white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;white-space: -pre-wrap;white-space: -o-pre-wrap;white-space: pre-wrap;word-break: break-all;white-space: normal;">
                            <h:outputText
                                value="#{custeffsumvar.oumStaffProfileForWbsCustEffort.profileName}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"
                            style="width: 500px;white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;white-space: -pre-wrap;white-space: -o-pre-wrap;white-space: pre-wrap;word-break: break-all;white-space: normal;">
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="sc_StaffProfileMenuSumm" required="true"
                                requiredMessage="Please select a Staff Profile."
                                title="Please select a Staff Profile."
                                converter="assetStaffProfileConverter"
                                value="#{custeffsumvar.oumStaffProfileForWbsCustEffort}">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Staff Profile" itemValue="" />
                                <f:selectItems id="sc_StaffProfileSelectitemsSumm"
                                    value="#{oumOpportunityBean.profileList}" var="scProfile"
                                    itemLabel="#{scProfile.profileName}" itemValue="#{scProfile}" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                ...

                <p:column>
                    <p:rowEditor />
                </p:column>

                ...
```

Now, through debugging, I am able to see that the oumOpportunityBean.setSCStaffProfile() is being invoked on row select, and the oumOpportunityBean.profileList List is getting populated with values, but the same is not reflecting in the "sc_StaffProfileMenuSumm" selectOneMenu.

So, looks like the update target of the rowSelect ajax event is not getting refreshed.

Please help with suggestions/resolution.

Comment: do you mean that `setSCStaffProfile` change value of the `p:selectOneMenu` but the update doesn't make it appear ?!?

Comment: did you check if your `p:selectOneMenu` have the right value i mean to understand if the problem is the data or the update ?!?

Comment: The setScStaffProfile() is populating the profileList List with the requisite values... that I am able to see through debugging. But the update is not refreshing the p:selectOneMenu.

Comment: change the update and update all the form ?!? and tell us does it work

Comment: The form is refreshing... that we can see from a flicker in the dataTable, but now the dataTable refuses to go to edit state (for a moment, it goes to edit state, and then comes back to the display state).

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation**

The problem is the update statement. As update target you define ":form_defineCustomerEffort:addCustEffortSummTable:sc_StaffProfileMenuSumm" which doesn't exist.

The ids of the drop down menus are numbered because you defined it within a p:dataTable. So your drop downs have ids like that:

```
form_defineCustomerEffort:addCustEffortSummTable:0:sc_StaffProfileMenuSumm
form_defineCustomerEffort:addCustEffortSummTable:1:sc_StaffProfileMenuSumm
```

and so on (have a look at the rendered html).

To update the current row it would be nice to do something like this:

```
update="@row(rowIndex)"
```

but that doesn't work. The Ajax-Behavior is definded once for the datatable and the update part is only evaluated once. At this time rowIndex is not set, that's why you would get an exception.

**Solution**

So in my opinion the best option you have is to pass the rowIndex as an argument to your listener method like that:

```
listener="#{oumOpportunityBean.setSCStaffProfile(rowIndex)}"
```

and update the right component in backend (you can remove the update attribute from your p:ajax):

```
public void setSCStaffProfile(int rowIndex) {
   // populate list
   // ...

   // update the right component
   RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form_defineCustomerEffort:addCustEffortSummTable:" + rowIndex + ":sc_StaffProfileMenuSumm");
}
```